# Is $(e^{u}+1)\Delta u+u=0$ the Euler-Lagrange equation of a functional energy?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Does there exist a functional energy $I$ such that $$(e^{u}+1)\Delta u+u=0$$ is the Euler-Lagrange equation associated with the energy functional $I$?

Comment: Try writing this as $\Delta u+ ue^{-u}=0$

Comment: Thank you! If we do not rewritten the equation, is there energy function?

Comment: If you don't allow for a rewriting of the equation, then you haven't formulated your question accurately. Then it sounds like you're asking specific terms in the Euler-Lagrange equation to each correspond to specific functional derivatives of a functional - as though you were really positing two separate equations rather than one.

Comment: @liding you seem to have changed the question so the manipulation I suggested doesn't immediately work

Comment: @AlexArvanitakis Well, if you admit sufficiently fancy functions in your potential ... $V(u)=u^2 /2 - u\ln (1+e^u ) - Li_2 (-e^u ) $ ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt agreed; I was just puzzled over the change

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt , I met  a more complex equation than this. This is a simplified version. The essential difficulty is the energy functional of $e^{u}\Delta u$, without changing the equation.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt, What is the mean of $Li_{2}(-e^{u})$?

Comment: $Li_2 $ is the dilogarithm function. It's still not clear what you're asking. You don't seem to be interested in the Euler-Lagrange equation per se, but somehow a functional which yields specifically $e^u \Delta u $ when you take a functional derivative. It would help if you would be clear about what it is you actually want.